# Angular 2 "Expression has changed after it was checked"

Tags: angular, momentjs

I'm using moment in my app and it shows "X Minutes ago" label this way:

`{{comment.created_at | amTimeAgo}}`

The number of minutes is updated automically (1 minute later it will be X-1 Miuntes ago".

When I'm away from the app, I'm trying to access it but I get the following error:

```
platform-browser.umd.js:962 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '8 Minutes ago'. Current value: '9 Minutes ago'
```

I read the data (date) once, in a method, from my API.

```
searchPeople(name)
{
    this.loading = true;
    this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + 'mode=search&name='+name)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {       
            this.loading = false;
            this.people = data;
            this.searchedName = name;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
}
```

How I can fix that?

Comment: Can you show the `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Sorry for confusion @GünterZöchbauer, it's a method not `ngOnInit()`.  Updated my question

Comment: Where is this method being called from? I don't see where it assigns `comment` or `comment.created_at`. What and where is `comment` and `comment.created_at`? Where and how do you calculate it?

Comment: `comment` is an object inside `people`. I get the `people`, and looping through each `person.comment`. I do not calculate the time, its automically as I said, I have the pipe from this package I installed: https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused from the pipe `amTimeAgo` to return differnt output for the same input. Obviously you compare `comment.create_at` with `Date.now()` and that results in different output when time goes by.

That's an impure pipe and you need to tell Angular that by setting `pure: false`:

```
@Pipe({ 
  name: 'amTimeAgo',
  pure: false
})
class AmTimeAgoPipe {
  ...
}
```

Comment: tried it without success: `
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'in a few seconds'. Current value: 'a few seconds ago'
`

Comment: I would need to see what you're doing. There are different things that can cause this error. Perhaps a new question with your code or maybe even a Plunker to reproduce would be better than continue discussing under this answer.